# E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting with SQLiteConstraintException

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, retrofit2

In this part of my app I trying to save the result data that getting from retrofit  onResponse method into sqlite database, but I getting multiple `E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting` errors with `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed:`

**The log**

```
    E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting kind=blogger#post etag="iHf3yWDE_geBgZ8U7rgZ_xuTeAQ/dGltZXN0YW1wOiAxNTQ4NTAwNzI5NjI4Cm9mZnNldDogNzIwMDAwMAo" id=2632206540636403989 published=2019-01-26T10:44:00+02:00 updated=2019-01-26T13:05:29+02:00 url=http://www.pro-cs-is.com/2019/01/view-see-saved-wifi-password-android.html content=<div dir="rtl" style="text-align: right;" trbidi="on">
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BgpwbrxNNxo/XEoAkKz4SQI/AAAAAAAAHQI/tNDvQUT1dLI6sb8aAU6xnAg0TK_HsNrmgCLcBGAs/s1600/%25D8%25B5%25D9%2588%25D8%25B1%25D8%25A9%2B%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D9%2585%25D9%2588%25D8%25B6%25D9%2588%25D8%25B9.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="720" data-original-width="1280" height="360" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BgpwbrxNNxo/XEoAkKz4SQI/AAAAAAAAHQI/tNDvQUT1dLI6sb8aAU6xnAg0TK_HsNrmgCLcBGAs/s640/%25D8%25B5%25D9%2588%25D8%25B1%25D8%25A9%2B%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D9%2585%25D9%2588%25D8%25B6%25D9%2588%25D8%25B9.jpg" width="640" /></a></div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL">
    <span lang="AR-EG" style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif; font-size: 14.0pt; line-height: 107%;">في بعض الأحيان ينسى مستخدمي الهواتف الذكية كلمة مرور شبكة ال WiFi المتصلين بها في الأماكن العامة أو العمل ويحتاجونها لمشاركتها مع الأصدقاء أو لأي أغراض آخرى، في هذا الموضوع سأقوم بشرح طريقتين لإستخراج كلمات مرور شبكات الواي فاي المحفوظة على هواتف الأندرويد.</span></div>
    <a name='more'></a><br />
    <blockquote class="tr_bq">
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><b>ملحوظة : جميع الطرق تحتاج إلى صلاحيات مدير النظام (Root)</b></span></span></blockquote>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif; font-size: 18.6667px;">إذا لم يكن بهاتفك صلاحيات مدير النظام يمكنك الإطلاع على هذا الموضوع&nbsp;<a href="https://www.pro-cs-is.com/2016/08/how-to-root-android.html" target="_blank">أفضل برامج للحصول على صلاحيات مدير النظام (Root) لجهازك الأندرويد</a></span><br />
    <br />
    <h3 style="text-align: right;">
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">الطريقة الأولى :</span></span></h3>
    <div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">عن طريق تطبيق <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=htmt.wifipassword" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">WiFi Password, IP, DNS</a></span></span><br />
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><br /></span>
    <br />
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-usMjRJwPBwE/XEr1aoQyhBI/AAAAAAAAHRM/eUj9EDxzrBkSKb6G09P2Y4iYPpzTO7SwACLcBGAs/s1600/WiFi%2BPassword%252C%2BIP%252C%2BDNS.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="632" data-original-width="1063" height="380" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-usMjRJwPBwE/XEr1aoQyhBI/AAAAAAAAHRM/eUj9EDxzrBkSKb6G09P2Y4iYPpzTO7SwACLcBGAs/s640/WiFi%2BPassword%252C%2BIP%252C%2BDNS.jpg" width="640" /></a></div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><br /></span></div>
    <div>
    <br /></div>
    <div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">بعد تحميل وتنصيب التطبيق قم بفتحه ثم إضغط على <b>Show WiFi Profiles</b>&nbsp;سيطلب التطبيق صلاحيات مدير النظام (root) قم بمنحه أياها</span></span><br />
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span><
E/SQLiteDatabase: <a href="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-R39qwUmqxBU/XEsCIo2NSLI/AAAAAAAAHRY/cLvsxmXKadkqTPrjgH_4JrIGLJvfwiobwCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A5-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A5-%25D9%25A4%25D9%25A7.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-R39qwUmqxBU/XEsCIo2NSLI/AAAAAAAAHRY/cLvsxmXKadkqTPrjgH_4JrIGLJvfwiobwCLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A5-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A5-%25D9%25A4%25D9%25A7.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">بعدها ستجد مباشرة جميع معلومات الشبكات التي قمت بالإتصال بها في هاتفك و كلمة المرور أمام كلمة <b>Password</b></span></span><br />
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <br />
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ikGMUxJyx8A/XEsFxFb3oRI/AAAAAAAAHRw/ByDdHVNO4Qgak5MLF49BnJT1m2q_timbQCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A5-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A4%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A7.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ikGMUxJyx8A/XEsFxFb3oRI/AAAAAAAAHRw/ByDdHVNO4Qgak5MLF49BnJT1m2q_timbQCLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A5-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A4%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A7.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    </div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><b>الطريقة الثانية :</b></span></span><br />
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span></div>
    <div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">عن طريق تطبيق <b><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Es File Explorer File Manger</a></b></span></span><br />
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <br />
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-a4bq9s_j3LI/XEsmj8E6x6I/AAAAAAAAHSM/ZiHDgBUKOMkYMIbMpeHPmmvMKuuXOWbLwCLcBGAs/s1600/Es%2BFile%2BExplorer%2BFile%2BManger.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="632" data-original-width="1110" height="364" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-a4bq9s_j3LI/XEsmj8E6x6I/AAAAAAAAHSM/ZiHDgBUKOMkYMIbMpeHPmmvMKuuXOWbLwCLcBGAs/s640/Es%2BFile%2BExplorer%2BFile%2BManger.jpg" width="640" /></a></div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span><span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">بعد تحميل وتنصيب التطبيق قم بفتحه ثم قم بالنقر على الثلاثة خطوط المتواجدين بالأعلى لفتح القائمة الجانبية</span></span><br />
    <span s
E/SQLiteDatabase: <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5J70yswDwPs/XEwRZWO5wkI/AAAAAAAAHSc/LbdMQ7RJOCgzhFT7dnRBeKqOx0gEXuQPACLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A3%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A7.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5J70yswDwPs/XEwRZWO5wkI/AAAAAAAAHSc/LbdMQ7RJOCgzhFT7dnRBeKqOx0gEXuQPACLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A3%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A7.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">من القائمة الجانبية قم بالنزول حتى تجد خيار <b>متصفح ملفات النظام</b>&nbsp;و إضغط عليه،&nbsp;</span></span><span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif; font-size: 18.6667px;">سيطلب التطبيق صلاحيات مدير النظام (root) قم بمنحه أياها</span><br />
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif; font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span>
    <br />
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-hV9L8BK77Vc/XEwSxR1SabI/AAAAAAAAHSo/9uziSP0y0GsHvaKeAseLi5Coi4zWXmuugCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A3%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A5%25D9%25A6.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-hV9L8BK77Vc/XEwSxR1SabI/AAAAAAAAHSo/9uziSP0y0GsHvaKeAseLi5Coi4zWXmuugCLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A3%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A5%25D9%25A6.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif; font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif; font-size: 18.6667px;">بعد منح التطبيق الصلاحيات، من نفس القائمة قم بالنزول إلى الأسفل حتى تجد خيار محلي أو Local إذا كانت لغة الهاتف بالإنجليزية</span><br />
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif; font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span>
    <br />
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wTj8cDUCqvE/XEwT_KiYjfI/AAAAAAAAHS0/Fb8gaeNopFg4Cwz9c8rIgNCWX2-mpTdDgCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A3.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wTj8cDUCqvE/XEwT_KiYjfI/AAAAAAAAHS0/Fb8gaeNopFg4Cwz9c8rIgNCWX2-mpTdDgCLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A3.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif; font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">بعدها اختر الجهاز/Device</span></span><br />
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <br />
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-t_nZeL67iqI/XEwUkXGZHRI/AAAAAAAAHS8/CckDMyA7j7kBeqsOqktMDx7hJZ9ATLtDgCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-t_nZeL67iqI/XEwUkXGZHRI/AAAAAAAAHS8/CckDMyA7j7kBeqsOqktMDx7hJZ9ATLtDgCLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">سيقوم التطبيق بفتح مجلدات النظام نحتاج إلى الوصول إلى هذا المسار</span></span><br />
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <br />
    <blockquote class="tr_bq">
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><b>data/misc/wifi/</b></span></span></blockquote>
    <br />
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-MBtwL3CjvH0/XEwVs2iZSsI/AAAAAAAAHTI/x5OUCa7sPNUW-s6MlAp6D-Qvqolgwm9igCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A5%25D9%25A4.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-MBtwL3CjvH0/XEwVs2iZSsI/AAAAAAAAHTI/x5OUCa7sPNUW-s6MlAp6D-Qvqolgwm9igCLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A5%25D9%25A4.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <br /></div>
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-j1voZIdovWE/XEwV-5uM4II/AAAAAAAAHTQ/HnqSCmMGnWsOEQSMBorDsxaty9NJnXa_ACLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A8.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-j1voZIdovWE/XEwV-5uM4II/AAAAAAAAHTQ/HnqSCmMGnWsOEQSMBorDsxaty9NJnXa_ACLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A8.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <br />
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-36O8nUlF20k/XEwWVO7oJ2I/AAAAAAAAHTY/3Uv4IBwUpeYGiIiArOWmaA7-yFx3bhhIgCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A3%25D9%25A9.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-36O8nUlF20k/XEwWVO7oJ2I/AAAAAAAAHTY/3Uv4IBwUpeYGiIiArOWmaA7-yFx3bhhIgCLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A3%25D9%25A9.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <br />
E/SQLiteDatabase: <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">وأخيراً ستجد ملف <b>wpa_supplicant.conf</b>&nbsp;والذي يحتوي على معلومات جميع الشبكات التي قمت بالإتصال بها على الهاتف، إضغط عليه لفتحه</span></span><br />
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <br />
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JSeNFvpHZj0/XEwXcvY_SJI/AAAAAAAAHTk/1eLPEKsQDD8KMSQk0wHjw8Acpnx3NegBgCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A2-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A6.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JSeNFvpHZj0/XEwXcvY_SJI/AAAAAAAAHTk/1eLPEKsQDD8KMSQk0wHjw8Acpnx3NegBgCLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A2-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A6.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><br /></span></span>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">قم بإختيار محرر النصوص الخاص بالتطبيق ES ، <b>لن يفتح بأي محرر نصوص آخر</b></span></span><br />
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><b><br /></b></span></span>
    <br />
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-s26DQfuJHbg/XEwX91ju0oI/AAAAAAAAHTs/SkTVzX6MjJ8AxxrO-uWvhXPRPfuYSgb7QCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-s26DQfuJHbg/XEwX91ju0oI/AAAAAAAAHTs/SkTVzX6MjJ8AxxrO-uWvhXPRPfuYSgb7QCLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A3-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><b><br /></b></span></span>
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;">ستجد مباشرة جميع معلومات الشبكات في هذا الملف من ضمنها كلمات المرور أمام كلمة <b>"psk"</b></span></span><br />
    <br />
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <a href="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-oS5PZl4rnX4/XEwYfFUUFBI/AAAAAAAAHT4/NS8GVEFg2mwqTkVbwUYT9iSyhChdyLVfgCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="1280" data-original-width="720" height="640" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-oS5PZl4rnX4/XEwYfFUUFBI/AAAAAAAAHT4/NS8GVEFg2mwqTkVbwUYT9iSyhChdyLVfgCLcBGAs/s640/Screenshot_%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A0%25D9%25A1-%25D9%25A2%25D9%25A4-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A9-%25D9%25A1%25D9%25A0.png" width="360" /></a></div>
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
    <br /></div>
    <blockquote class="tr_bq">
    <span style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><b>بعض الشبكات لن تجد هذا السطر و هذا معناه إنها شبكة مفتوحة "بدون ك�
E/SQLiteDatabase: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: items.id (code 1555)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:783)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1548)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
        at www.pro_cs_is.com.ItemsDBHelper.addItem(ItemsDBHelper.java:72)
        at www.pro_cs_is.com.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:198)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:821)
```

> Which I understood from the log that there was a mistake in writing the Syntax for creating the ITEMS_TABLE but I reviewed it several times and everything seems to be fine
> **Note:** I trying to replace **KEY_ID** primary key index to the second and make **KEY_KIND** first in the sql clause such as its location in the defined class but the same result!

**The ItemsDBHelper class**

```
    public class ItemsDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "itemsInfo";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "items";
    private static final String KEY_KIND = "kind";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_PUBLISHED = "published";
    private static final String KEY_UPDATED = "updated";
    private static final String KEY_ETAG = "etag";
    private static final String KEY_URL = "url";
    private static final String KEY_SELFLINK = "selfLink";
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
    private static final String KEY_LABELS = "labels";

    public ItemsDBHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.e("oncreate","oncreate");
        String CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + " ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_KIND+" TEXT,  "+KEY_PUBLISHED+" TEXT, "
                +KEY_UPDATED+" TEXT, "+KEY_ETAG+" TEXT, "+KEY_URL+" TEXT, "
                +KEY_SELFLINK+" TEXT, "+KEY_CONTENT+" TEXT, "+KEY_LABELS+" TEXT)";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.e("onupgrade","onupgrade");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addItem(Item item){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID,item.getId());
        values.put(KEY_KIND,item.getKind());
        values.put(KEY_PUBLISHED,item.getPublished());
        values.put(KEY_UPDATED,item.getUpdated());
        values.put(KEY_ETAG,item.getEtag());
        values.put(KEY_URL,item.getUrl());
        values.put(KEY_SELFLINK,item.getSelfLink());
        values.put(KEY_CONTENT,item.getContent());
        values.put(KEY_LABELS,convertListToString(item.getLabels()));

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Item getItem(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_KIND,KEY_PUBLISHED,
                        KEY_UPDATED,KEY_ETAG,KEY_URL,KEY_SELFLINK,KEY_CONTENT},KEY_ID+"=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null);
        Item item=null;
        if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            item = new Item();
        }
        return item;
    }

    public List<Item> getAllShops(){
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase dp = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = dp.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        if(cursor!=null){
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    Item item = new Item();
                    item.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                    item.setKind(cursor.getString(1));
                    item.setPublished(cursor.getString(2));
                    item.setUpdated(cursor.getString(3));
                    item.setEtag(cursor.getString(4));
                    item.setUrl(cursor.getString(5));
                    item.setSelfLink(cursor.getString(5));
                    item.setContent(cursor.getString(6));
                    item.setLabels(convertStringToList(cursor.getString(7)));

                    items.add(item);
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    private static final String LIST_SEPARATOR = "__,__";

    public static String convertListToString(List<String> stringList) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String str : stringList) {
            stringBuilder.append(str).append(LIST_SEPARATOR);
        }

        // Remove last separator
        stringBuilder.setLength(stringBuilder.length() - LIST_SEPARATOR.length());

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static List<String> convertStringToList(String str) {
        return Arrays.asList(str.split(LIST_SEPARATOR));
    }
}
```

**and I used it like this in the response method**

```
final Call<PostList> postList = BloggerAPI.getService().getPostList(url);
    postList.enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PostList> call, Response<PostList> response) {
            PostList list = response.body();
            token = list.getNextPageToken();
            items.addAll(list.getItems());

            for (int i = 0 ; i< items.size();i++) {
               itemsDBHelper = new ItemsDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
               itemsDBHelper.addItem(items.get(i));
            }

            Item item1 = itemsDBHelper.getItem(0);
            Log.e("TEST ITEM 01",item1.getTitle()+ "\n" + item1.getUrl());
            Item item2 = itemsDBHelper.getItem(1);
            Log.e("TEST ITEM 01",item2.getTitle()+ "\n" + item2.getUrl());



            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PostList> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error occured",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the **id** column is not UNIQUE, this isn't an error as such rather that the exception has been trapped, as effectively INSERT OR IGNORE is being used, but is being written to the log. However, the row, when this happens will not be inserted.

The **id** column is defined using INTEGER PRIMARY KEY this implies a UNIQUE constraint, it additionally makes the column an alias of the **rowid**, which then makes the column have a special attribute/handling case. That is, if no value is specified then SQLite will generate a unique value. That value will be a unique 64 bit signed integer, initially 1 and then generally 1 greater that the last value.

Typically no value is supplied for such a column and the SQLite generated value is used.

I'd suggest that you change to using the typical use and thus amend your **addItem** method accordingly e.g. :-

```
public long addItem(Item item){ //<<<<<<<<<< returns long (id assigned by SQLite)
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(KEY_ID,item.getId()); //<<<<<<<<<< allow SQLite to assign id
    values.put(KEY_KIND,item.getKind());
    values.put(KEY_PUBLISHED,item.getPublished());
    values.put(KEY_UPDATED,item.getUpdated());
    values.put(KEY_ETAG,item.getEtag());
    values.put(KEY_URL,item.getUrl());
    values.put(KEY_SELFLINK,item.getSelfLink());
    values.put(KEY_CONTENT,item.getContent());
    values.put(KEY_LABELS,convertListToString(item.getLabels()));

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    db.close();
}
```

After inserting the row you should then set the **id** in the **item** object with the value returned from the **addItem** method, if that object is then going to be used subsequently.

Comment: thank you for explanation, I got it, the issue because the id's that retrieving from server like this "2632206540636403989"
"8995646748402888275"
What do you think how to solve this problem?

Comment: @MahmoudMetawee Either you want to ignore the duplicate id's (i.e. do nothing as such, just ignore messsages) from the server if they are unique on the server (perhaps investigating why you are getting the duplicates) or alternately 
if duplicates are allowed make the column so that it is not unique i.e. not INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, just INTEGER and perhaps indexed. Of course you'd then need to consider what should be done with the **getItem** method. Basically what needs to be done is dependant upon the data from the server.